Is the question of Lebesgue measurability of projective sets “leaning” one way or the other?
A lot of independence results (Continuum Hypothesis, existence of Suslin trees, etc.) can seem (to my mind anyway) a bit “esoteric”, i.e. not impacting in an obvious way to “normal” mathematics (areas of math other than “foundational” subjects like set theory).
But the question of whether all projective subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are Lebesgue measurable stands out to me as an independence result that seems not “esoteric” at all, being a pretty basic question about which sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ have a “volume” (according to Lebesgue measure).
I’m wondering to what degree this question is truly “undecided”. That is, is there anything like a consensus leaning in one direction as to what the “right” answer “should” be?

This article by Hugh Woodin seems to argue pretty emphatically for Projective Determinacy as an additional “canonical” axiom, which would settle the Lebesgue measurability of projective sets question. But I wouldn’t assume that Woodin’s view represents a “consensus”.


I am not sure what esoteric would mean exactly in a mathematical context, but people working in analysis and other fields using the Lebesgue measure are probably more concerned with the issue whether all sets are Lebesgue-measurable, than with specifically projective sets, which would seem to be of more relevance to set theory than analysis.  There is the Solovay model where all sets are Lebesgue-measurable so in principle analysts could work there, but the foundational system there cannot be extended beyond ZF+ADC (in particular, the full axiom of choice has to be left out), which is an inconvenience to analysts who wish to use the full strength of the Hahn-Banach theorem, for example.
At any rate, my impression is that set theorists today tend to side with accepting ever stronger cardinal axioms, in the hope of developing an "infinite ascent" scheme that would ultimately justify consistency.  Unfortunately, this does not work out quite as smoothly as hoped.  There is a recent set of slides by Hamkins from 2021 where he explains why this does not quite work out (I am not sure if this ever became an article or not).  Modulo that proviso, the tendency would be to accept strong cardinals necessary for projective determinacy.  This in particular would make it "true" (as per Woodin) that projective sets are Lebesgue-measurable.
Other than that, it seems to me that there are very few examples of independent statements (beyond the Continuum Hypothesis) where there is no intuitively preferred truth value; and there are certainly no purely arithmetic examples of this.  If one were found, this would constitute a "Radical Scenario" in Gaifman's terminology.

I did a bit more digging on this and found the article here (the one titled “Set Theory”) which states (in section III.B.1) that ZFC+CH implies existence of a non-measurable projective set of reals. So if Projective Determinacy were regarded by most to be “intuitively preferred”, that would imply (albeit indirectly) a sort of “consensus” that also $\neg CH$ is “intuitively preferred” over $CH$. But my impression (I think?) is that such a “consensus” does not exist regarding $CH$.

As to why I focused on projective subsets, Martin and Steel explain the intuition I had in mind probably better than I could, saying of independence results: “Others are in some ways more concrete: e.g. questions of descriptive set theory which concern not arbitrary sets of real numbers…but only simply definable sets of real numbers”

@NikS it is not the case that ZFC+CH implies the existence of a non-measurable projective set of reals. I don't have access to the linked article; are you sure you've read it correctly?

@NoahSchweber : Weird that you can’t access the page (I’m not logged in to sciencedirect.com, yet I can access). Anyway, upon rereading, I see there’s a major ambiguity (unclear writing) I hadn’t noticed before. It says “ZFC+CH implies a negative answer to the measure problem”, but it’s ambiguous as to what the phrase “the measure problem” refers to, since that paragraph discusses two different questions re Lebesgue measure. I guess I assumed wrongly that “the measure problem” meant “are all projective sets of Lebesgue measurable?”

@NoahSchweber : But ZFC + “V=L” $\implies$ “there exists a non-Lebesgue measurable projective set of reals”, correct?

@NikS V=L implies that there is a non-measurable $\Pi^1_2$ set, yes. As to the measure problem, that's a different statement.
